# Dataset web service from android eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, web-services, dataset

Can any one tell me how to display a dataset value from the web service by consuming it from android eclipse?

I have tried these things so far

```
public class Demo_webserviceActivity extends Activity
{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

   private static String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
   private static String METHOD_NAME = "GetName";
   private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/GetName";
   private static String URL = "http://122.248.240.105:234/Service1.asmx?WSDL";

   Button btnFar;
   EditText txtFar,txtCel;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);

       btnFar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnFar);

       txtFar = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtFar);
       txtCel = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtCel);

       btnFar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
       {

                  public void onClick(View v)
              {
                    //Initialize soap request + add parameters
              SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);       

              //Use this to add parameters
              request.addProperty("Fahrenheit",txtFar.getText().toString());

              //Declare the version of the SOAP request
              SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

              envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
              envelope.dotNet = true;

              try {
                    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

                    //this is the actual part that will call the webservice
                    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

                    // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.
                    SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;

                    if(result != null)
                    {
                          //Get the first property and change the label text
                          txtCel.setText(result.getProperty(0).toString());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Response",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
              } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
              }
              }
        });
```

**web method**

```
public class GetName 
{

public String GetName(String Fahrenheit){
    return(Fahrenheit);
}
}
```

Here is my log cat for reference

**logcat**

```
06-11 17:03:57.760: D/AndroidRuntime(283): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
06-11 17:03:57.760: D/AndroidRuntime(283): CheckJNI is ON
06-11 17:03:57.890: D/AndroidRuntime(283): --- registering native functions ---
06-11 17:03:58.520: D/AndroidRuntime(283): Shutting down VM
06-11 17:03:58.530: D/dalvikvm(283): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1  entries
06-11 17:03:58.580: I/AndroidRuntime(283): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
06-11 17:03:58.980: D/AndroidRuntime(291): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
06-11 17:03:58.980: D/AndroidRuntime(291): CheckJNI is ON
06-11 17:03:59.150: D/AndroidRuntime(291): --- registering native functions ---
06-11 17:03:59.750: I/ActivityManager(58): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.demo.webser/.Demo_webserviceActivity }
06-11 17:03:59.820: D/AndroidRuntime(291): Shutting down VM
06-11 17:03:59.820: D/dalvikvm(291): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
06-11 17:03:59.865: I/AndroidRuntime(291): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
06-11 17:04:00.560: I/ActivityManager(58): Displayed activity com.demo.webser/.Demo_webserviceActivity: 780 ms (total 780 ms)
06-11 17:04:05.930: D/dalvikvm(115): GC_EXPLICIT freed 2114 objects / 95232 bytes in 117ms
```

Comment: What does that even mean? And what you have tried so far?

Comment: Sebastin please visit my question again i have editted with what i have done so far

Comment: which platform you are using to develop **web service** so that i can help depend on that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I considered you are developing web service in java.
No there is no data type as data set in java but if you want you can return response as array of String.It mean get response(table) in 2D array of string and return that response.

And for your reference for creating webservice in java use this Tutorial [How to create java based web service](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/BottomUpAxis2WebService/bu_tutorial.html).

If you have any doubts regarding this or any other doubts you can write me.